# Bad Memory Access for declared Structs with Arrays in C++ (using Xcode)

Tags: c++, xcode, exc-bad-access

I have the following C++ program (code below) on Xcode 13.1 for macOS Big Sur Version 11.7:

1. **header_example.hpp**:
   1.1) *type_of_struct_a* is a struct type which contains a 3D array of size [3][3][3] in addition to a 2D array of size [X_COORDINATE][Y_COORDINATE], where X_COORDINATE and Y_COORDINATE are integer values #defined by macros. Arrays are, as an example, of type short although I could have chosen any other type such as: int, uint8_t, etc.
   1.2) *type_of_struct_b* is a struct type which contains a 1D array of size [8] where each element in the array is of type *type_of_struct_a* in 1.1) above.
   1.3) *type_of_struct_c* is a struct type which contains a 3D array of size [3][X_COORDINATE][Y_COORDINATE] using the mentioned define macros. In this case, the 3D array contains elements of type uint8_t.
2. **main.cpp**:
   2.1) The header **header_example.hpp** in 1) is included.
   2.2) I declare one instance of *type_of_struct_c* and another instance for *type_of_sruct_b*.
3. **ISSUE**:
   3.1) When executing the code, it compiles without any errors as long as #define X_COORDINATE 664 and #define Y_COORDINATE 664 (or any other value <=664). Good!
   3.2) However, if now we increase the coordinates to 665 or any other higher number (665, 666, 667, etc): #define X_COORDINATE 665 and #define Y_COORDINATE 665, then the execution is stopped by lldb with an error coming from the assembly code (see below):

> Thread 1: **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** (code=2, address=0x7ffeef3ffff8)

The error is coming from the following assembly code line in libsystem_pthread.dylib`___chkstk_darwin:

`->  0x100391b33 <+55>:  testq  %rcx, -0x8(%rcx)`

[image: Assembly code showing the error]

4. **CODE USED**:
   **header_example.hpp**:

```
    #define X_COORDINATE 666
    #define Y_COORDINATE 666
    struct type_of_struct_a{
    short array_3D[3][3][3];
    short array_2D[X_COORDINATE][Y_COORDINATE];
    };
    struct type_of_struct_b{
    type_of_struct_a array_1D_with_structs_a[8];
    };
    struct type_of_struct_c {
    uint8_t struct_c_3D[3][X_COORDINATE][Y_COORDINATE];
    };
```

**main.cpp**:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "header_example.hpp"
    int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    type_of_struct_c instance_struct_c;
    type_of_struct_b instance_struct_b;
    std::cout<<"END" << std::endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

**My impression is that there's a memory issue related to the declaration of the array inside the struct. Any insight on why this problem is happening? Any input to fix the bug?**
Thank you.

Comment: Enable address sanitizer and run code again. Then read report carefully everything should become clear.

Comment: The size of `type_of_struct_a` will be at least `887166` bytes.The size of `type_of_struct_b` will be eight times that (`7097328` bytes). And `type_of_struct_c` is `1330668` bytes. The two structures are in total `8427996` bytes. Over the 8 MiB stack size that is the default for macOS (IIRC).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so if there's an overload of the stack size, do you have any suggestion to avoiding such overload? Should I not use the structs or?

Comment: Smaller arrays? Use `std::vector` instead? Pointers and heap allocation (but rather go for vectors instead)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Can you be a bit more concrete? :)

Comment: what more concrete? You are using too much stack memory, the solution is to use less stack memory. `std::vector` allocates elements on the heap.

Comment: Now I see a problem you have instance of extremely large type on stack. `type_of_struct_a` is large and `type_of_struct_b` aggregates it. Simply stack is unable to handle such big types.

Answer (score 0):

Most of you pointed out that the amount of data for the memory stack was excessive. I think one of the answers (from Marek R) summarises the problem quite well:

> "Now I see a problem you have instance of extremely large type on stack. type_of_struct_a is large and type_of_struct_b aggregates it. Simply stack is unable to handle such big types."